# spring-cloud-contract-verifier cleanup messages in camel kafka topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, spring-cloud-contract

During contract test I run main `FLOW`, which produces 2 events into different kafka topics (`TOPIC_1` and `TOPIC_2`). And I have two different tests to check sending of this events (`TEST_1` for `TOPIC_1` and `TEST_2` for `TOPIC_2`). So both `TEST_1` and `TEST_2` runs the same `FLOW`, and for `TEST_1` I have side effect of sending event into `TOPIC_2`, and for `TEST_2` - `TOPIC_1`. Consider example, where I run `TEST_1` and then `TEST_2`. During `TEST_2` I will have 2 events inside `TOPIC_2` - one produced by `TEST_1` and the second produced by `TEST_2`. And of course, my `TEST_2` will fail, because during the verification it supposes to receive message, produced by himself, nothing else.

So, that's why I need to skip all old messages in all topics before each test. How does it possible to do with usage of `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.internal.ContractVerifierMessaging`

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution where I poll all messages from each endpoint inside CamelContext

```
@Autowired
private org.apache.camel.CamelContext camelContext;

@org.junit.Before
public void cleanUpCamelEndpoints() {
    for (Endpoint endpoint : camelContext.getEndpoints()) {
        try {
            PollingConsumer pollingConsumer = endpoint.createPollingConsumer();
            Exchange exchangeToSkip;
            while ((exchangeToSkip = pollingConsumer.receiveNoWait()) != null) {
                log.debug("Skipped side effect exchange: {}", exchangeToSkip);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.debug("Exception while receive exchange to skip: " + exception);
        }
    }
}
```